# How to make bootstrap badge vertically center aligned?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/8mfr1x79/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="lis-group-item" href="#">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tristique erat ac nisi finibus, tempor commodo turpis dictum. Proin tempor neque a ullamcorper maximus. <span class="badge badge-default pull-right">A long badge</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any easy way so that whole text of the "a" element on the left gets adjusted towards a little left so that the badge aligns vertically in center?

I can give fixed width to the content on left, but I am concerned about all device sizes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not without changing the structure or massively overwriting the existing CSS Framework. Plus links aren't supposed to be that long.

Answer (score 5):

Flexbox could do that

```css
a.list-group-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
a .text {
  flex: 1;
}
a .badge {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
      <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tristique erat ac nisi finibus, tempor commodo turpis dictum. Proin tempor neque a ullamcorper maximus. </span><span class="badge badge-default">A long badge</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
      <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor </span><span class="badge badge-default">A long badge</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but got into problem with this, even after I used pull-right, the badge comes to the left if the text is not full line long.

Comment: Updated the answer...I omitted the `flex:1` on the first span.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use table-cells and get rid of the float.

https://jsfiddle.net/8mfr1x79/4/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="lis-group-item table" href="#">
        <span class="tableCell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tristique erat ac nisi finibus, tempor commodo turpis dictum. Proin tempor neque a ullamcorper maximus. 
        </span>
        <span class="tableCell">
          <span class="badge badge-default">A long badge</span>
        </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.table{
  display: table;
}

.tableCell{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: The class `.table` is already used by bootstrap, might bring some problems. Though this might be not a beautiful solution, it's simple.

Comment: Sorry, not a regular bootstrap user, feel free to call your table class anything you like though.

Comment: "table" will do me for now until someone posts a better solution. Really thanks Mike. I will surely not use "table" as class to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Missunderstood your question. Hold on.

Switch the position of the badge with your text, the text will flow around it.

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mfr1x79/3/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a class="lis-group-item" href="#">
            <span class="badge badge-default pull-right">A long badge</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tristique erat ac nisi finibus, tempor commodo turpis dictum. Proin tempor neque a ullamcorper maximus.
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** this only works because of the badges `.pull-right`/`float: right;`

Comment: Really thanks. It did the trick, but still its not in perfect center on my Chrome. Any way to make it perfect vertical center?

Comment: I actually missunderstood your question, for it to be centered vertically you need to position it absolute, which might get tricky.